# Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1045

I'm trying connect me to database MySQL server but the console show me **`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`** I don't know why. Please help me. In my file `my.cnf` I have something like this,

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# To allow mysqld to connect to a MySQL Cluster management daemon, uncomment
# these lines and adjust the connectstring as needed.
#ndbcluster
#ndb-connectstring="nodeid=4;host=localhost:3306"

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[ndbd]
# If you are running a MySQL Cluster storage daemon (ndbd) on this machine,
# adjust its connection to the management daemon here.
# Note: ndbd init script requires this to include nodeid!
connect-string="nodeid=2;host=localhost:3306"

[ndb_mgm]
# connection string for MySQL Cluster management tool
connect-string="host=localhost:3306"

[client]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you connect via console? (ommiting passwords if supplied on commandline)

Comment: Sure, **`Hectors-MacBook-Pro:~ hlozano$ mysql -uroot -p`**

Comment: Did you set a password during installation? :) Just hitting `Enter` on password prompt doesn't help? And you're sure you're entering proper password? (Sorry for the obvious questions, just want to make sure) :)

Comment: Oh of course, I reinstall the MySQL server because not up the databases. When I restart my MAC did not entry to database.

Comment: From your screenshot (which does include passwords :P) I see that earlier attempt to change password to 'mysqli' didn't work, and current password for your mysql isn't 'mysql' either :) If this is a fresh installation, then password is empty and you can just hit `Enter` to a password propmpt.

Comment: Not, I try it not password but `access denied` I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: If you really don't remember the pass anymore, you can add `skip_grant_tables` to `[mysqld]` section of your my.cnf, restart server it will let you in without a password, then you can change password by updating `mysql.user` table and restart mysql removing the `skip_grant_tables` option.

Comment: Added as an answer, if that solved your issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't remember the pass anymore, you can add `skip_grant_tables` to `[mysqld]` section of your `my.cnf`, restart server, it will let you in without a password, then you can change password by updating `mysql.user` table and restart mysql removing the `skip_grant_tables` option.

Answer (score 0):

The `-p` flag denotes the requirement for a password. There should be a second prompt after typing what you typed requesting the password. For example:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
$ Enter password:
```

Then you type the password.